# when I click on a element returns multiple times

Tags: javascript, foreach

this is my code(*without css file*):

```js
var taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput"),
  taskList = document.getElementById("taskList");

taskList.addEventListener("click", changesLi);

function addTask() {
  if (!taskInput.value) return alert("Please enter a task.");

  var li = createLi(taskInput.value);
  taskList.prepend(li);
  taskInput.value = "";
}

function createLi(title) {
  var li = document.createElement("li"),
    span = document.createElement("span"),
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    remove = document.createElement("a"),
    done = document.createElement("a"),
    doneImg = document.createElement("img"),
    removeImg = document.createElement("img");

  span.textContent = title;
  li.className = "task";
  div.className = "links";
  done.href = "#";
  done.className = "done";
  doneImg.alt = "done";
  done.appendChild(doneImg);
  remove.href = "#";
  remove.className = "remove";
  removeImg.alt = "remove";
  remove.appendChild(removeImg);
  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(done);
  div.appendChild(remove);

  return li;
}

function changesLi(e) {
  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("remove")) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }

  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("done")) {
    const tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".done");
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      task.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(e.target);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="task-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();addTask()">
  <input id="taskInput" placeholder="New task..." autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="submit" />
</form>
<ul id="taskList"></ul>
```

When I click on a button that contains the **done** class, the **e.target** value returns to me as an array each time.
The first time I click, nothing returns. The second time, it returns the target once, the third time, the target twice, and so on...
No matter how much I searched, I didn't get any results. Where is my problem?

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners to all the `.done` buttons when the user clicks on one of them? You're adding more and more event listeners, and they all run when the user clicks.

Comment: @barmar that's my problem! what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the user clicks on a `done` button, you're adding a click listener to *all* the `done` buttons. Adding a listener doesn't replace previous listeners, so each time they click it adds another listener. When they click again, it runs all the listeners that do the `console.log(e.target)`, as well as the original listener that adds another listener to all the buttons.

You should just log what you want in the original listener, without adding any additional listeners.

```js
var taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput"),
  taskList = document.getElementById("taskList");

taskList.addEventListener("click", changesLi);

function changesLi(e) {
  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("remove")) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  } else if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("done")) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("span").textContent);
  }
}

function addTask() {
  if (!taskInput.value) return alert("Please enter a task.");

  var li = createLi(taskInput.value);
  taskList.prepend(li);
  taskInput.value = "";
}

function createLi(title) {
  var li = document.createElement("li"),
    span = document.createElement("span"),
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    remove = document.createElement("a"),
    done = document.createElement("a"),
    doneImg = document.createElement("img"),
    removeImg = document.createElement("img");

  span.textContent = title;
  li.className = "task";
  div.className = "links";
  done.href = "#";
  done.className = "done";
  doneImg.alt = "done";
  done.appendChild(doneImg);
  remove.href = "#";
  remove.className = "remove";
  removeImg.alt = "remove";
  remove.appendChild(removeImg);
  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(done);
  div.appendChild(remove);

  return li;
}
```

```html
<form class="task-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();addTask()">
  <input id="taskInput" placeholder="New task..." autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="submit" />
</form>
<ul id="taskList"></ul>
```

Comment: I can't believe the solution was so simple!
Thank you for your great solution

Comment: I was trying to get each element for that I replace image of element with another new image! in fact my problem still unresolved!

Comment: `e.target` will be the image that they clicked on, you can do `e.target.src = "newimg.png"` to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click a '.done' element, you are binding a new click event to each '.done' element:

```js
  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("done")) {
    const tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".done");
    
    // for each '.done'
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      // add another callback for the click event
      task.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(e.target);
      });
    });
  }
```

And you don't need to do that. Just log the target:

```js
  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("done")) {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
```